# Puzzled over basic exponentiation problem with complex argument

Tags: exponentiation

I can't figure out where is my erroneous thinking in the following elementary use of exponents. I have used Mathematica to verify that I don't know what I'm doing.

$$ a^{bc}=\left(a^{b}\right)^{c} $$
Mathematica says "True".

$$ e^{bc}=\left(e^{b}\right)^{c} $$
Mathematica says "True".

$$ e^{ibc}=\left(e^{ib}\right)^{c} $$
Mathematica says "True" ($i=\sqrt{-1}$).

$$ e^{i2\pi c}=\left(e^{i2\pi}\right)^{c} $$
Mathematica says "False".

FWIW I used `PowerExpand[]` on each of these expressions in Mathematica and put them inside a `TrueQ[]` function. I know that $ e^{i2\pi} = 1 $, that $ 1^{c}=1 $, and that $ e^{i2\pi c} $ is generally some point on the unit circle depending on the value of $c$ and thus a complex number with unit magnitude.

Please show me what is wrong.

Comment: In equation 3, I'm pretty sure I is being interpreted as a real variable and not imaginary complex unit.

Comment: @fleablood No, Mathematica uses a special symbol for the imaginary unit and I have been careful to use it.

Comment: @heropup Thank you for the Mathematica lesson; however, my question is not how to use Mathematica but why $e^{i2\pi c}\neq\left(e^{i2\pi}\right)^{c}$. For example, if c = 1/2, LHS = -1 but RHS = 1.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `PowerExpand` clearly states:

> The transformations made by `PowerExpand` are correct in general only if `c` is an integer or `a` and `b` are positive real numbers.

This is why you are getting erroneous results.  In the last expression, if $c$ is not an integer, $e^{2\pi i c} \ne (e^{2\pi i})^c$; e.g., try $c = 1/2$.

Do not use *Mathematica* commands without first understanding the documentation.